# Why the last element of tcp/ip message's byte array in java is 0?

Tags: java

I am sending a byte array from a client to the server. The client's byte array is:

```
0 52 2 0 72 3c 5 80 0 c0 0 8 10 c 22 38 4e 5b 15 1f 29 1e 0 0 0 0 0 0 a 0 b 16 21 2c 37 c
22 38 20 41 62 2 1c 11 1 0 15 4 2c 0 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30
30 30 30 30 31 35 0 9 4d 79 20 50 61 72 73 65 72
```

but the byte array received by the server is:

```
0 52 2 0 72 3c 5 80 0 c0 0 8 10 c 22 38 4e 5b 15 1f 29 1e 0 0 0 0 0 0 a 0 b 16 21 2c 37 c
22 38 20 41 62 2 1c 11 1 0 15 4 2c 0 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30
30 30 30 30 31 35 0 9 4d 79 20 50 61 72 73 65 0
```

plz let me know as soon as possible.

Comment: Could you show the code you use to send and receive data?

Comment: Show us the code, how do you send this array.

Comment: if you use datagrams for example , or arrays, it just might have zeros there which you dont overwrite.

Comment: actually noting that the last 72 is converted to 0 , are you sure you actually send the 72, if you dont send it accidentally, for example by having a loop with an off-by-one error , then it is still zero on the receiving end array.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided any code, which makes it hard to diagnose things, but I *suspect* you're ignoring the return value from `InputStream.read()` which indicates how many bytes have been read.

It's entirely possible that the message is broken up by the network, and you need to issue multiple `read()` calls to fetch it all. You should note the return value of `read()` and ignore any bytes outside the relevant range.

Either that, or you haven't actually sent the data correctly, of course, probably due to an off-by-one error. Again - without code, it's hard to say.